# How to write integration test cases for Redis sentinel fail over scenraio

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-sentinel

I have been using Redis and using stackexchange client library in c#. I have written some integration test cases using third party library called 'Redis inside'.

Now that I have to write integration test cases for sentinel fail over case.

Do anyone have ever worked on this?

Thanks!